# How to resolve error where gem from git repository "is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, rubygems, bundler, foreman

I have been tearing my hair out for a week trying to get a project to run locally.

`bundle install` works fine but when I run `foreman start`, I get this error:

**git://github.com/{repo_path}.git (at master) is not checked out. Please run `bundle install`**

I've trawled through Stackoverflow and still can't get this to work.

OS: Lion
Rails: 3.1.3
Ruby: 1.9.3-p0
Bundler: 1.0.21

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needless to say, I've spent a lot of time trying everything to fix this. Following ALL of the troubleshooting steps here finally resolved it:

https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/blob/master/ISSUES.md

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Be sure your foreman processes are specified to execute within the current bundler environment. Example line in the Procfile in your app root:

```
web: bundle exec thin start
```

Comment: Thanks but that's already done. I just installed the thin gem to see if that was missing and causing the error; but it made no difference. It must have something to do with the location of gems installed from git but I can't figure it out. Where does bundler install gems?

Comment: There's a lot of info about gem locations on [Bundler's bundle install page](http://gembundler.com/v1.2/bundle_install.html).

To ensure you're using gems from your application, rather than the system, do this:

    bundle install --path vendor/bundle

Comment: Oh, and doing the above solves the original problem of not locating a git-based gem (at least in my case, YMMV).